# Python Webdriver - How can I select a radio button based upon the text of a separate label?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, radio-button, label

Using Python WebDriver, how can I select a radio button based upon the text of a separate element such as this label?

My current code has the ability to click the radio button by id. But I have no idea how it is possible to click it when I am depending on text from a completely separate element.

The following is a pic of what i'm up against.

All help is greatly appreciated! =)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a simplified example of your html on the screenshot, and assuming you want to get radio button which following sibling has "test text2", you need to use [xpath axes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp):

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><input id="test_id" type="radio" value="123" /></td>
<td>test text</td>
<td>test text2</td>
<td>test text3</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

XPath would be: `//tr/td[contains(text(),"test text2")]/preceding-sibling::td/input`

The logic is:

- get an element with specific text
- go to previous sibling element (sibling == same level element)
- now go deeper to `td/input` from there